# How to send value of *NgFor option select in Reactive Forms

Tags: angular

I have a form in Angular, the select option has data coming from a web api. What I want to know is how to assign the selected value to form value when sending at the moment it is just [object object]. The ngFor statement is:

```
<select class="form-select" formControlName="u_address" placeholder="Enter address">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
   <option *ngFor="let item of customerAddress" [value]="item">
   {{item.address}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Then in the component.ts file it is:

```
  u_address: new FormControl(this.customerAddress),
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share your customerAddress object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to the following code

```
[value]="item.address"

<select class="form-select" formControlName="u_address" placeholder="Enter address">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
   <option *ngFor="let item of customerAddress" [value]="item.address">
   {{item.address}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

Please use ngValue instead of value.

```
<select class="form-select" formControlName="u_address" placeholder="Enter address">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
   <option *ngFor="let item of customerAddress" [ngValue]="item">
   {{item.address}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: you can use [value] if you needn't an object, (Shohel wrote [value]="item.adress"). If you need the whole object it's true that you must use [ngValue]="item"

Comment: Thanks, needed object and didn't know about this fix